# Gremlin BatchGraph in python

Tags: gremlin, gremlinpython

I cannot find an implementation of BatchGraph (https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Batch-Implementation) in python connector (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gremlinpython)

Could anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've received an answer from [TinkerPop Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1702), that BatchGraph was deprecated.

In general, massive batch loads (say millions of things) should be done with [OLAP](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#hadoop-gremlin) and anything less is probably best done with a groovy script. If you want to do it from python i would just write a parameterized script like:

```
data.each {
  g.addV('name', it.name, 'age', it.age).iterate()
}
```

where "data" is a parameter you pass with the script. "data" is just a List and the number of maps represents your batch size. Use sessionless requests so that Gremlin Server auto-commits. If you have further follow up questions, please ask them on the gremlin-users mailing list - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In gremlin_python you can concat the traversals and finally send it to gremlin like this:

```
ret1 = g
ret1 = ret1.V()
ret1 = ret1.limit(4)
ret1.toList()

output:
[v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4]]
```